# Capricorn One, what happened to the protagonists?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, capricorn-one

In the movie [Capricorn One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capricorn_One), we see that both the astronauts Willis and Walker are captured by NASA officials.

I wonder, is there an in-universe explanation to what happened to them thereafter?

Was it implied that they were executed or that they were simply held captive somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## There is no definitive answer in the movie<sup>*</sup>.

We do not see what happens to Willis or Walker but it's certainly *implied* that they are executed.

When news of their capture is relayed back to NASA they are always referred to in the *past tense* and when the helicopter pilots attempt to stop Brubaker from escaping they have no hesitation in using deadly force to do so.

The fact that we do **not** see **all three** astronauts at the end lends further weight to the theory that Brubaker was the only survivor.

---

<sup>*</sup>There were TWO novelisations of the movie (a UK version and a US version) which may add more detail but I have not been able to locate an e-book copy of either to verify.